# Generic DataResponse with Alamofire and ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, generics, alamofire, objectmapper

I want to create a custom class for Alamofire so I will be able to call the request over and over again in various classes. In order to do that I need to pass the model class that extends to Mappable in DataResponse. But I got many errors.

This is my current code in the custom class:

```
func callAPI<T: Mappable>(response: T){
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
        let result = response.result.value as! BaseData

    }
}
```

And this is my code when i call the method:

```
func data() {
    let manager = ManagerData(url: url)
    manager.callAPI(response: Model.self)
}
```

This is my Model class:

```
class Model: BaseData {
var point: String?
var list: [Voucher]?

override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map: map)

    totalPoint <- map["TOTAL_POINT"]
    list <- map["VOUCHER"]
}
```

}

```
class BaseData: Mappable {
var status: String?
var message: String?

required init() {

}

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    status <- map["STATUS"]
    message <- map["MESSAGE"]
}
```

}

On `manager.callAPI(response: Model.self)` error is `Argument type Model.Type does not conform to expected type Mappable`.

Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Add the also the (simplified) Model class declaration to your question.

Comment: I've added the model class. Thanks @Jeroen Heier